# why g++ doesn't support functional with allocator constructor on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, stl

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char** argc)
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::function<void (void)> f(std::allocator_arg,x.get_allocator());
    return 1;
}
```

Using : `g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11` 
It failed on `Ubuntu 15`, my `g++ version is 5.2.1`. it's all ok on `XCode` and `VS2015`. and I check `/usr/include/c++/5/functional`, it has no constructor for allocators. I check `www.cplusplus.com`, and It defines the constructor with allocator. 
Someone can tell me how to fix this problem or I have to change the g++ stl,
How to change g++ stl with other stl ? I have downloaded sgi stl source codes.
Please help ! Thanks a lot .

Comment: `allocator_arg` is a constant - your code makes no more sense than `std::function<void (void)> f(PI);`.

Comment: Until GCC 6.1.0, `std::function` with allocator is still not supported, the source has comment `// TODO: needs allocator_arg_t`

Comment: thank you very much. I give up using allocator~

Answer (score 2):

The use of allocator in `std::function` has many issues.

[What's the point of std::function constructor with custom allocator but no other args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596021/whats-the-point-of-stdfunction-constructor-with-custom-allocator-but-no-other)

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2386

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0302r0.html

Looking at the g++ `functional` source, it obviously does not make use of any allocator `construct` for dynamic allocation, it plainly uses `new` and `delete`.

So, I am not sure how you can provide your allocator to do the heap allocation. But, one bad idea is to derive from `function` and overload the `new` and `delete` operator. I would suggest you to **NOT** to go down this path. It's a very very **BAD** idea.